# Why are Moabites not allowed to join the Jewish congregation?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

Male Moabites are not allowed to join the Jewish congregation (Deut. 23) (i.e. marry a Cohen, Levi, or Yisrael). The reason given is their ancestors lacked gratitude.

Is this due to bad qualities which presumably gets transmitted to their offspring (but somehow only the male ones) or is it meant to be a remembrance as to how severe ingratitude is or perhaps some other reason.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean to ask why both a male Moabite convert and his children for all generations are not allowed to marry into the Jewish people, I will offer the following answer which points to this law being a lesson, and not a genome issue.

Chazzal mention that it was not expected of the women to go out of their houses, so there is nothing held against them in this matter. As the Chinuch in mitzvah 561 quotes and elaborates:

(יבמות ע"ו ע"ב) שהזכרים דוקא מבני עמון ומואב הם ובניהם עד עולם הוא שאסורין לבא בקהל אבל הנקבות מותרות מיד שתתגיירנה. ואמרו בטעם זה לפי שהאיש דרכו לקדם אבל לא הנקבות כלומר שהן לא היתה ידן בנבלה כשלא קדמו ישראל בלחם ובמים שאין דרך האשה לצאת והאל לא יעות משפט לענוש האשה בשביל נבלת האיש חלילה לאל מרשע.
The implication, to me at least, is that there was nothing better about the females of Moav. They were simply uninvolved with the atrocity. Which would mean your other option that this is simply a lesson for life is correct.

The Chinuch right afterwards also seems to say this quite clearly.

והודיענו הכתוב מזה גודל מעלת גמילות חסדים והרחקת מדת הנבלה והכילות ועל כן צונו לקבוע שנאה עמהם שהשחיתו והתעיבו להראות תכלית רשעם ונבלותם שלא להקדים אפילו בלחם ובמים קהל גדול עייפי הדרך העוברים בגבולם ואשר שכרו עליהם מואב את בלעם לקללם. ואף על פי שמצריים שעבדו בנו וצערונו זמן רב לא נתרחקנו מהם כי אם עד דור שלישי וידענו בזה שיפה לו לאדם לעשות כמה חטאים ולא נבלה אחת גדולה כי בהסכמתו בעשיית הנבלה המכוערת ולא יחוש לגלות דעתו ובושתו נגד עמים רבים מראה בזה רוע מזגו ותכלית פחיתותו וכי אין בו עוד תקנה להכשיר עצמו ולהטיב מעשהו ונתחזק עוותו עד שלא יוכל לתקון ואיש כמוהו איננו ראוי להתערב בעם הקודש המבורך.

This lesson from the Moabites is giving us an insight into individuals and judgement of personality for all eternity. If someone enslaved you or hires a hitman to take care of you, there is hope that he can be a decent person. If he brazenly ignored you in your desperate time of need, there is no hope for him.

Comment: so they were severely punished to be made into an example.

Comment: That's what it seems like.

Comment: chinuch writes "to hate them..." which sounds to me a bit like they are also still guilty, no?

Comment: This is not an issue of children dying for the sins of the fathers. Basically the way I see it this is not a punishment for what the fathers did per say. Imagine the fathers had all commit suicide. We wouldn't ask how could the children not exist because of the act of the fathers. Same here. The fathers commit marrying-into-the-Jewish-nation-suicide. It's no longer an option for the children. We have nothing against them. They can convert. We will love them. But insofar as to teach this lesson, they have that restriction.